# Instagram error 403 account inactive

Tags: instagram

I'm getting this in my console when I log `[response bodyAsString];`:

```
BodyAsString: <response>
  <status>error</status>
  <code>403</code>
  <message>Account Inactive</message>
</response>
```

Not sure why my account (Instagram API) is inactive.  Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Where's the rest of the code?

Comment: @AndyHolmes Thats all there is for it.  What else were you thinking should be there?

Comment: Are you accessing an API? Is this the only code on the page? What were you expecting to return? etc etc

Comment: @AndyHolmes Yup, I'm accessing the Instagram API.  Just using `NSLog` to see if I'm getting any sort of response in my `UIViewController` yet.  Thanks!

Comment: @Nit what code are you talking about?  Thanks!

Comment: How are you accessing the API? What code are you *using* to get the error

Comment: @AndyHolmes I'm using my Client ID

Comment: You're making this harder than it needs to be. Show everyone your code you are using to access the API. Maybe you have an error in the code you've written, until then, no one really knows what you've done do they.

Comment: @AndyHolmes not trying to make it difficult, just wasn't sure if I was being asked for another error "code" or the actual programming "code"

Comment: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/media/recent/?client_id=x"]`

Comment: No i meant your actual code lol. When using StackOverflow you need to be adding ALL relevant code to your question so that people know what you are doing. Showing just the error won't always tell people what the issue might be, it could just be a typo, but we have nothing to review.

Comment: @AndyHolmes totally.  Need me to post more code, or did the `NSString` help enough?

Comment: Post all relevant code that involves the API, there might be something further up causing the issue

Comment: @AndyHolmes thanks for showing a noob the ropes, you ROCK!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 403 error means your access to the page is forbidden. Try resetting your IP address and removing and proxies you have running and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I just reset my IP address.  I'm not sure how to remove any proxies running, isn't that something I do through a browser though?  Or is it something different that you can let me know how to do?